# Math.Abs vs. casting twice to retrieve absolute value

Tags: c#, collections

I am currently in the middle of watching a video on [C# Collections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnCbj-Tjl6c&index=1&list=PLD_n_feSn9l3nWCEsxCAko27u5H3Z65j8) and came across the following bit of code that piqued my interest:

```
int hashKey = (int)((uint)hashCode % capacity);
```

This was changed from the previous:

```
int hashKey = Math.Abs(hashCode % capacity);
```

The first implementation leaves hashKey with a value of **47** while the second implementation leaves it at **49**, the former giving me the expected result.

I manually added the string "Hello" into my hash table so I expect to retrieve the bucket containing that word when I call my function as follows:

```
LinkedString results = hash.GetAllAtHash("Hello".GetHashCode());
```

Here is the function for completeness:

```
public LinkedString GetAllAtHash(int hashCode)
{
     int hashKey = (int)((uint)hashCode % capacity);
     //int hashKey = Math.Abs(hashCode % capacity);
     return values[hashKey];
}
```

Is there any significance in using one way over the other? Why do they both return different values and if I hadn't watched the video, how would I have been able to tell what was wrong without getting a compile/run-time error?

Thanks

Comment: Changed your title because, at first glance, I thought this question involved casting to/from the `double` data type.

Comment: All we need is a repeatable calculation distributes fairly between buckets. The important part is missing from the question... it's that this calculation should match for both storage and retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

It is all because of the `uint` casting. If you write the code like the following, you will be in the way to get the same result:

```
 int hashKey = (int)((uint)(hashCode % capacity));
```

I mean just put the `hashCode % capacity` inside parenthesis and then cast to the `uint`. If you do this, you will get the result of negative to the second `hashKey`. 
Therefore, the following `hashKey`s are the same:

```
int hashKey1 = hashCode < 0 ? -(int)((uint)(hashCode % capacity)) : (int)((uint)hashCode % capacity);
int hashKey2 = Math.Abs(hashCode % capacity);
```

I shoule have mentioned that without parenthesis, it first cast the `hashcode` to `uint` (not the result of `%`) and if `hashCode` is negative, its unsigned will be another number which is not the same as `hashCode` necessarily.